# How do I loop through all the stocks and find the 10 stocks with the highest Sharpe ratio using R program?

Tags: equities, programming, finance, sharpe-ratio

I am recently doing a project, which I need to apply Sharpe ratio to all the stocks. How do I loop through all the stocks and find the 10 stocks with the highest Sharpe ratio using R program? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Use function `rank` on the vector of the Sharpe ratios; then use `which(ranks<=10)` where `ranks` is the output of `rank`.

Comment: Do you have the data already? If you assign Sharpe ratios to each stock, just sort by the Sharpe ratio and take the top 10?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you should avoid using loops in R unless absolutely necessary since iteration is very slow in R. Some newer data classes improve performance, but in general its always best to use a "vectorised" method if available.

You could use either `order` or `rank` to get the 10 stocks with the highest Sharpe Ratio.

Lets assume you have the following data in R:

```
mydata <- as.data.frame( cbind( scrip=letters, sharpe_ratio=seq(from=-0.25,to=1.00,by=0.05) ) )
mydata$sharpe_ratio <- as.numeric( as.character(mydata$sharpe_ratio ) )
```

**Method 1**: Sort and then pick up top 10:

```
mydata[ order(mydata$sharpe_ratio, decreasing =TRUE) ,][1:10,]
   scrip sharpe_ratio
26     z         1.00
25     y         0.95
24     x         0.90
23     w         0.85
22     v         0.80
21     u         0.75
20     t         0.70
19     s         0.65
18     r         0.60
17     q         0.55
```

**Method 2**: Find the rank and pick top 10:

```
sharpe_ranks <- rank( mydata$sharpe_ratio )
mydata[ sharpe_ranks[ sharpe_ranks>(length(sharpe_ranks)-10) ] ,]
   scrip sharpe_ratio
17     q         0.55
18     r         0.60
19     s         0.65
20     t         0.70
21     u         0.75
22     v         0.80
23     w         0.85
24     x         0.90
25     y         0.95
26     z         1.00
```